Combining object-fit: contain and hard-coded aspect-ratio on img
I am trying to combine object-fit: contains with aspect-ratio: 1.5 /* hardcoded number */ on an img.
The image remains square, however:


// Javascript for example resizing panels only.

const leftPanel = document.querySelector('.left-panel');
const rightPanel = document.querySelector('.right-panel');
const panelHandle = document.querySelector('.panel-handle');

let isDragging = false;

panelHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDragging = true;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
});

function onMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDragging) return;

    const containerWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    const newLeftWidth = e.clientX;

    if (newLeftWidth < 0 || newLeftWidth > containerWidth - panelHandle.offsetWidth) return;

    const newRightWidth = containerWidth - newLeftWidth - panelHandle.offsetWidth;

    leftPanel.style.width = `${newLeftWidth}px`;
    rightPanel.style.width = `${newRightWidth}px`;
}

function onMouseUp() {
    isDragging = false;
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
}
/* img scaling */

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;

  /* has no effect */
  aspect-ratio: 1.5;
}

/* panel resizing */

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.left-panel,
.right-panel {
  height: 100%;
}

.left-panel {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-panel {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-handle {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
<div class="left-panel">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" draggable="false" />
</div>
<div class="panel-handle">
</div>
<div class="right-panel">
  <div>
    Drag the center bar to resize these panels.
  </div>
  <div>
    The image should be a 3:2 aspect ratio but is it's instrinsic square.
  </div>
</div>



I want to force the image to aspect-ratio: 1.5, and then use automatic letterboxing.
Conceptually, I want to set aspect-ratio: 1.5, and then have css choose either width: 100% or height: 100% depending on the aspect ratio of the container.
Is this possible in pure CSS? Many related questions are about maintaining an image's existing aspect ratio, which is not what I want.
X for my Y: I have an image from a server which is the wrong aspect ratio. The server is some firmware device that outputs in an aspect ratio which is twice as wide as it should be displayed (for technical reasons). I know the correct display aspect ratio and can set it directly. The <img /> is inside a dynamic container, e.g. from react-resizable-panels.
Edit:
Current behavior (image of regular grid with square aspect ratio):

Responsive size
Not taking my aspect-ratio

 and 
Desired behavior

Responsive size
Force aspect-ratio to 3:2, ignoring original image size

 and 

Thank you to the other answerers for their time.
I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66721382/3554391
Can't explain why it works but there ya go.


// Javascript for example resizing panels only.

const leftPanel = document.querySelector('.left-panel');
const rightPanel = document.querySelector('.right-panel');
const panelHandle = document.querySelector('.panel-handle');

let isDragging = false;

panelHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDragging = true;
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
});

function onMouseMove(e) {
  if (!isDragging) return;

  const containerWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  const newLeftWidth = e.clientX;

  if (newLeftWidth < 0 || newLeftWidth > containerWidth - panelHandle.offsetWidth) return;

  const newRightWidth = containerWidth - newLeftWidth - panelHandle.offsetWidth;

  leftPanel.style.width = `${newLeftWidth}px`;
  rightPanel.style.width = `${newRightWidth}px`;
}

function onMouseUp() {
  isDragging = false;
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
}
/* img scaling */

.left-panel {
  position: relative;
}

.left-panel-img-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1.5;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* panel resizing */

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.left-panel,
.right-panel {
  height: 100%;
}

.left-panel {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-panel {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-handle {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
<div class="left-panel">
  <div class="left-panel-img-wrapper">
    <img class="left-panel-img" src="data:image/bmp;base64,Qk2mAAAAAAAAAD4AAAAoAAAADQAAAA0AAAABAAQAAAAAAAAAAADEDgAAxA4AAAIAAAACAAAAAAAA//////8AAAAAAAAAAAERAREBEQAAAREBEQERAAABEQERAREAAAAAAAAAAAAAAREBEQERAAABEQERAREAAAERAREBEQAAAAAAAAAAAAABEQERAREAAAERAREBEQAAAREBEQERAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==" draggable="false" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-handle">
</div>
<div class="right-panel">
  <div>
    Drag the center bar to resize these panels.
  </div>
  <div>The image to the left should be 3:2 and centered in its panel vertically and horizontally.</div>
</div>




It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. But you can place img with object-fit: contain in a div, which will have an aspect-ratio: 1.5:


// Javascript for example resizing panels only.

const leftPanel = document.querySelector('.left-panel');
const rightPanel = document.querySelector('.right-panel');
const panelHandle = document.querySelector('.panel-handle');

let isDragging = false;

panelHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDragging = true;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
});

function onMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDragging) return;

    const containerWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    const newLeftWidth = e.clientX;

    if (newLeftWidth < 0 || newLeftWidth > containerWidth - panelHandle.offsetWidth) return;

    const newRightWidth = containerWidth - newLeftWidth - panelHandle.offsetWidth;

    leftPanel.style.width = `${newLeftWidth}px`;
    rightPanel.style.width = `${newRightWidth}px`;
}

function onMouseUp() {
    isDragging = false;
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
}
/* img scaling */

.left-panel-img{
    aspect-ratio: 1.5;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    outline:solid 1px yellow;
}

img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

/* panel resizing */

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.left-panel,
.right-panel {
  height: 100%;
}

.left-panel {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 50%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.right-panel {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-handle {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
<div class="left-panel">
  <div class="left-panel-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" draggable="false" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-handle">
</div>
<div class="right-panel">
  <div>
    Drag the center bar to resize these panels.
  </div>
  <div>
    The image should be a 3:2 aspect ratio but is it's instrinsic square.
  </div>
</div>




Sorry for not being clear. In your example, I want the image to behave exactly like your left-panel-img div, with the image stretched to reach the 3:2 aspect ratio.

Then just set object-fit: cover

To make an image fit a particular aspect ratio, you have three choices:

Letterbox – with object-fit: contain
Clip – with object-fit: cover
Distort – omit object-fit or use object-fit: fill (the default value)

It seems that you want to distort the image, so just remove your object-fit style.


// Javascript for example resizing panels only.

const leftPanel = document.querySelector('.left-panel');
const rightPanel = document.querySelector('.right-panel');
const panelHandle = document.querySelector('.panel-handle');

let isDragging = false;

panelHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDragging = true;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
});

function onMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDragging) return;

    const containerWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    const newLeftWidth = e.clientX;

    if (newLeftWidth < 0 || newLeftWidth > containerWidth - panelHandle.offsetWidth) return;

    const newRightWidth = containerWidth - newLeftWidth - panelHandle.offsetWidth;

    leftPanel.style.width = `${newLeftWidth}px`;
    rightPanel.style.width = `${newRightWidth}px`;
}

function onMouseUp() {
    isDragging = false;
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
}
.left-panel-img {
  aspect-ratio: 1.5;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.left-panel,
.right-panel {
  height: 100%;
}

.left-panel {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 50%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.right-panel {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-handle {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
<div class="left-panel">
  <div class="left-panel-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" draggable="false" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-handle">
</div>
<div class="right-panel">
  <div>
    Drag the center bar to resize these panels.
  </div>
  <div>
    The image should be a 3:2 aspect ratio but is it's instrinsic square.
  </div>
</div>




Thanks! This is extremely close. The one small issue is that if the image isn't large enough it won't expand to fill the frame (e.g. change the src to /100 or open the example in a full page and expand the left panel).
For example: https://jsfiddle.net/4odw68uq/14/

Ah wait, sorry, this clips the image, which is not what I want. Clearly I'm not making sense in my question, I'll edit in some screenshots and photoshops.

I’ve adjusted the snippet to make the container width: 100% instead of max-width: 100%. This stretches the container, which then stretches the image if it is small. And I’ve added a second snippet which stretches (distorts) the image rather than clipping it, if that’s the effect you actually want. Note that it is important to describe your requirements clearly and precisely. Anyway, if you want to make an image fit a particular aspect ratio, your choices are (a) letterbox (with object-fit: contain), (b) clip (with object-fit: cover), or (c) distort (without object-fit).

Genuinely, I thought I had described my requirements clearly, but evidently not. Apologies.
I've added some images to my post to explain further. The "desired" set of images were produced by manually choosing either width: 100% or height: 100% based on the panel size.

Okay, you want to distort the image, that is now clear. A picture is worth a thousand words. I have updated my answer.



This works well (on firefox at least) when the panel is narrow, but not when it is wide.


This does not seem to change the image's aspect-ratio on chrome :(



Snippet updated to fix the issue visible in Chrome. You just need to add overflow: hidden to your aspect-ratio container.

I very much appreciate the time you've put into this. This only works for a single axis, however—if the panel gets wide, the image starts stretching to fill the entire panel, rather than having bars to its left and right. I've figured out how to get the image to size correctly, on both axes, here: https://jsfiddle.net/jwtsm3g1/277/. Now the problem is how to center that (I had to remove the flexbox to get this sizing to work). Might be a red herring.

I think I've got it, I'll post an answer. Thanks again.
